# Cakephp3: how to use toList()

Tags: cakephp

I wanted to output this data as comma separated list:

```
<td><?= $this->Text->toList($trainer->roles); ?></td>
```

But what I get is a json string like

```
{ "id": 5, "abbreviation": "SUP+2", "description": "Superior +2", "created": "2016-11-29T12:31:50", "modified": "2016-11-29T12:31:50", .....
```

What do I have to do to get a list of the field "abbreviation" like

> red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo and violet

Comment: If you want to get data of abbreviation in list then check this link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#table-find-list

Comment: Hi, the link you gave me look to me how to find data within the controller. But I am in my template and the data is present. But I can't see an example what to do in my case? Or I do not understand what do you want to point me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you have the data and you want to concat the abbreviation only for the array?

Then you can try [Hash::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) to get the array of abbreviation only and then implode the array with comma like this

```
$results = implode(", ",Hash::extract($yourArray, '{n}.abbreviation'));
```

This will help

Comment: The purpose of [toList](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/text.html#converting-an-array-to-sentence-form) is to generate a "humanized list" i.e. "foo, bar _and_ zum". This answer would be more correct as `$results = $this->Text->toList(Hash::extract(...` - I.e. the right way to use `toList` is to pass it a flat list, not avoid using it all together. You've addressed the (relatively speaking) hard part but not answered the question asked.